# Scala mutator naming conventions and requirements

Tags: scala, properties, naming-conventions

I am having some trouble understand the naming in Scala with respect to mutators.  Here is the part that I am having trouble understanding:

```
class Company {
  private val _name: String = _

  def name = _name

  def name_=(name: String) {
    _name = name
  }
}
```

So I understand that the _name is the private String, and the first def name is the getter/accessor while the second is the setter/mutator.  Essentially,  I understand what the code means and does, but I am not sure what is personal preference vs code standards/the required way to do it.  Will all mutators have the _ suffix and is it standard to prefix private attributes with an underscore or is that personal preference?

Or can I just define the mutator as the following?

```
def name=(name: String) {
    _name = name
}
```

Similarly, do I have the prefix the private val with the underscore or could I just change it to:

```
def name=(name: String) {
   name = name
}
```

I got the above code from [Scala Naming Conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) and [Daniel Spewak's Accessors/Mutators](http://daniel-spewaks-scala-style-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/naming_conventions/methods/accessors_mutators.html)

Comment: Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: The provided links are quite clear about conventions. But if talking about compiler restrictions, Scala compiler requires you to name your setter as `{getterName}_=`, and this is the only requirement (except for the other part of the signature). You can name your private var whatever you want or even skip it at all and have your getter and setter computable

Comment: While the links are clear about conventions, they are not clear about requirements. I think what Archeg wrote is a basis for a good answer.

Comment: I do not think this is a [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) - nothing in the name is related to the type (it is true it is denoted as such in the linked article, and underscore is a kind of Hungarian prefix, but still ...).

Answer (score 0):

*These are all good questions. Some of them are covered by the article from the Scala documentation you've liked, specifically in the part about [Accessors/Mutators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#accessorsmutators).*

#### Naming of mutator methods

*In a nutshell, the `name_=` form is not special syntax but rather a naming convention enforced by the specification.*

Let's look at what `scalac` produces at the JVM bytecode level when you declare a plain old `var`. Understanding the bytecode produced by `scalac` is by no means necessary to understand the higher-level workings of the language, but many people learning Scala have some experience with Java and, though that, some intuition of what is possible in the JVM and what isn't. I think this is the closest we can get to as the *why* of some of the decisions that were made in the specification of Scala.

Here I have a source file called `Var.scala`:

```
trait Var {
  var name: String
}
```

I compile the source to a *class file* and decompile it using `javap`:

```
$ scalac Var.scala 
$ javap Var.class 
Compiled from "Var.scala"
public interface Var {
  public abstract java.lang.String name();
  public abstract void name_$eq(java.lang.String);
}
```

As we can see, a `var` in a trait declares two JVM methods, a getter, and a setter. The getter takes the name of the `var`, while the setter has a bit of a weird name. Here, `$eq` is just how an `=` in a Scala identifier is encoded by `scalac` in the class file it produces. This is part of the Scala specification and is required for binary compatibility between different compilation units.

So the name of the setter as seen from Scala is simply `name_=`. This is also part of the Scala specification. When we write a statement that sets the value of a `var`, a call to a method with a name of that form is generated. When we write a statement that just reads the `var`, a call to the first method is generated.

Instead of declaring a `var`, we could just as well declare those two methods directly:

```
trait ValAndDef {
  val name: String
  def name_=(newName: String): Unit
}
```

Compiling and decompiling this will show the exact same methods as before. There is also nothing preventing you from declaring only one of those methods, which would create a member which can only be read but not written, or vice versa.

#### Naming of the private packing field

Until now, I've only talked about *declaring* a field. *Implementing* the field means also adding storage to the `var` or implementing the methods when declared directly. Declaring a `var` in a *class* instead of a *trait* will automatically add a field for storing the value of the `var`:

```
class VarClass {
  var name: String = _
}
```

```
$ javap -private VarClass.class
Compiled from "VarClass.scala"
public class VarClass {
  private java.lang.String name;
  public java.lang.String name();
  public void name_$eq(java.lang.String);
  public VarClass();
}
```

If you decide to implement the field using a pair of methods, you will have to declare such a private field yourself. The Scala specification does not say anything about how that field should be named in that case (it is private and thus not part of any interoperability concern).

The only thing "official" I can find is a paragraph in the article I linked at the top, which advocates the `_name` naming pattern for the backing field, while also stating:

> While Hungarian notation is terribly ugly, it does have the advantage of disambiguating the _name variable without cluttering the identifier.

So it is up to you whether you want to follow that guidance or not. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯